# Asp.net fancybox parent page refresh when button clicked in iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, parameters, fancybox

I make the closing process via that code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "", "parent.$.fancybox.close();", true);
```

No problem Its work but I want to parent page refresh only when clicked to button.

Right now parent page always refreshing.

How can I pass parameter to parent page when iframe closing. Because I want to control to refresh.

in parent page fancbox code:

```
$(".various").fancybox({
                    maxWidth: 850,
                    maxHeight: 650,
                    fitToView: false,
                    width: '70%',
                    height: '70%',
                    autoSize: false,
                    closeClick: false,
                    openEffect: 'none',
                    closeEffect: 'none',
                    afterClose: function () { 
                    parent.location.reload(true);
                }
                });
```

forexample

```
                    afterClose: function () { 

//if (parameterFromIframe==1) {

                    parent.location.reload(true);

//}

                }
```

Thank you for your helps